# AWS AppSync only returns 10 items on query on connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm new to AppSync and trying to see how this works and what's the proper way to set this up.

I created schema.graphql looks like below.

```
type User @model {
  id: String!
  following: [String]
  follower: [String]
  journals: [Journal] @connection(name: "UserJournals", sortField: "createdAt")
  notifications: [Notification] @connection(name: "UserNotifications", sortField: "createdAt")
}

type Journal @model {
  id: ID!
  author: User! @connection(name: "UserJournals")
  privacy: String!
  content: AWSJSON!
  loved: [String]
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
```

and this created queries.js automatically by AppSync.

```
export const getUser = `query GetUser($id: ID!) {
  getUser(id: $id) {
    id
    following
    follower
    journals {
      items {
        id
        privacy
        content
        loved
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
    notifications {
      items {
        id
        content
        category
        link
        createdAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
}
`;
```

I noticed that querying `getUser` only returns 10 `journals` items and not sure how to set that to more than 10 or proper way to query and add more journals into that 10 items that were queried by `getUser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not pass the `limit` argument explicitly in your query, the Request Mapping Template of the `journals` resolver defaults it to 10 items. If you would like to change this default value, go to your schema page on the AppSync console, navigate to the `journals` field, found under the Resolvers section of the schema page. This will then show the resolver definition for this field, and you can then update the default value of **10** to anything you like. Alternatively, you can pass this as your query argument.

FYI - This default value is defined in the **amplify-cli** repo on GitHub and can be found [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/master/packages/graphql-connection-transformer/src/resources.ts#L132).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It makes sense but I'm still confused. You meant that I have to modify `graphql > queries.js` file that contains `getUser ` function which was generated automatically by `schema.graphql`? so it can take `limit` argument?

Comment: Eventually, I like to set the limit to 30 and add an infinity scrolling to add another 30 items as you scrolling down(with nextToken). However, I'm not sure if 
 `API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getUser, {id: Uuid}))` that I'm currently using will support what I want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, so you can pass in the `limit` and `nextToken` fields for the journals selection field. For example, in your query, you can use, `journals(limit:30, nextToken: "blah") { items { ...`. This way you can write a client logic that caches the previous "nextToken" and uses it in the GraphQL query as it's fetching additional pages.

Comment: So, yes, you can modify the `graphql > queries.js` file to your liking, and pass the values from externally.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I think I'm finally understanding how this works! I have two more questions if you don't mind answering :) 

Is it better to modify `graphql > queries.js` or just write a custom query cause I thought `graphql > queries.js` is auto generated and any change u make will go away once I change the `schema.graphql` file. 

Is there a way to set the limit argument in `schema.graphql` file?

Comment: Glad this was helpful to you. I'd suggest you write and maintain custom queries, and reference it from your code, if you are trying to run something different from the `graphql > queries.js`. This is because, this file will be overwritten upon changes to your annotated schema. Also, you cannot update the schema.graphql, and it is not a clean way as well. It is cleaner to pass this as an argument (or update your Mapping Template with a different default value, if you don't want to pass it as an argument). Let me know if you need anything, happy to help.